# Is it faster to clone() or create new elements for large number of iterations?

Tags: jquery, performance, clone

**FIRST QUESTION**
I'm creating a book that contains a page for each day of the year. These pages will be dynamically created every time the "book" (i.e,. the app) is opened. The pages are all of the ame UI - they just contain different DB populated data and different ID attributes.

Suppose I have:

```
<div id="1" class="page">
    <form action="addEntry">
        <input type="text" name="entry">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

I need 364 more of these.

I could do:

```
<script>
    var page = $('.page'),
        pages = $('<div>').addClass('pages'),
        bod = $('body');

    page.appendTo(pages);

    for(var i = 0; i<364; i++) {
        var nextPage = page.clone().attr({ id:, i+2 }).html(populate()).appendTo(pages);
    }
    pages.appendTo(bod);
</script>
```

**OR**

```
<script>

var bod = $('bod'),
    pages = $('<div>').addClass('pages');

for(var i=0, i<364, i++) {       
    var page = $('<div>').addClass('page').attr(id, i+2),
        form = $('<form>').attr('action', 'addEntry').append(
            $('<input>').attr({ type: 'text', name: 'entry' }).append(
            $('<input>').attr({ type: 'submit', value: 'submit' });

        form.appendTo(page).appendTo(pages);
}

pages.appendTo(bod);

</script>
```

Does one of these approaches yield better performance than the other? or is one considered better practice than the other?

**QUESTION 2**
Is the method I used to insert the pages into the DOM the preferred way? or should I have been building up a string of HTML inside the loop that I then do a `pages.html(html)` outside of the loop?

Comment: The most performant method regarding speed is to use [documentFragment](https://davidwalsh.name/documentfragment) and append all the result once loop completes. But if you don't have to append thousand elements, use the method/logic you find the most readable and the most maintenable. Usually this is bad practice to mix plain js methods and jq ones, asking for trouble. FYI, you could test all your snippets on [jsperf.com](https://jsperf.com/). And BTW, i'd suggest to add only the displayed page and create the following one on the fly or depending user navigation

Comment: ⇈⇈ Appending 365 `form` at once really looks like bad regarding UX

Comment: @A. Wolf - thanks - the 1st part definitely makes sense as well as the part about creating just the displayed page, but which plain js and jq methods are being mixed? Also why is multiple `<form>`s in an app bad UX?

Comment: `but which plain js and jq methods are being mixed?` I meant if you start using documentFragment and mix it with some handy jquery methods, but your code is fine regarding the fact you don't mix plain js and jq. Now i was just saying i guess there is better way to handle your expected behaviour than using 365 forms. But as i don't know exactly what you are doing, i can only guessing

Comment: ohhhhhhh now I get what you're saying about the mixing.... Re: all the forms - the book is a journal with a page for each day of the year. There are animated page turns where you can see the content on the back of your current page as well as the content on the page + or - 2 pages. You can also swipe, click or drag through pages very quickly. I don't have any real data in the db yet so i'm not sure how quickly the pages can be rendered on the fly. But I am essentially using a `<form>` per page so that only the new or changed entries are submitted to the backend code that updated the database.

Comment: Should I be rendering the form on the fly for just the 2 pages that are visible at a time?